# error with rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed the rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem and its shownin the list of gems.
I have generated the autocomplete-rails.js file and included it in my layout.
I am trying to implement auto complete field for the users table on the names field.
I am getting an error saying

```
"undefined local variable or method `autocomplete' for #<#<Class:0xb709ac24>:0xb7099a7c>"
```

Please let me know where I had went wrong.

releases_controller.rb

```
class ReleasesController < AuthorizedController
  # GET /releases
  # GET /releases.xml
    autocomplete :users, :name 

def new 
    @release = Release.new
       respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @release }
         end
  end
```

My view file:

```
= form.autocomplete_field_tag 'tester_name', :data-autocomplete=>"releases_autocomplete_users_name_path"
```

my routes file:

```
get 'releases/autocomplete_users_name'
```

Error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `autocomplete' for #<#<Class:0xb71cc1d8>:0xb71caa90>):
        37:             -puts "testers=#{@testers}"
        38:             = form.label :tester_tokens, "Testers"
        39:             = form.text_field :tester_tokens
        40:             = autocomplete_field_tag 'tester_name', :data-autocomplete=>"releases_autocomplete_users_name_path"
        41:             - @testers.each do |tester|
        42:               %tr
        43:                 %td=tester.name
```

Answer (score 1):

please update your route file this may be help you, as it is working for me:

```
resources :releases do
    get :autocomplete_user_name, :on => :collection
  end
```

chears..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't use tag, as in the [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) page.

try

```
form.autocomplete_field :tester_name, autocomplete_tester_name_releases_path
```

I think you should also create a virtual field on releases model if you want to use :tester_name.

if you want to grab the id, then you can create a hidden field and add :id_element => '#some_element' to the autocomplete helper